# How to get thumbnail photo from m3u8 live stream on ios?

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayer

Is there any way to get stream thumbnail photo from periscope or any other `.m3u8` video stream on ios?

I tried to download video with `requestThumbnailImagesAtTimes:timeOption:` but cant get the thumbs, any suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I was playing the video through a UIWebView.  When I called `loadRequest:` the video would automatically start playing and I just wanted to show the preview image of the video with the play arrow on top of the preview image.

The way I did it was to set the `mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction` property to YES like this:

```
[cell.webView setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction:YES];
```

So this way it shows a preview image and does not automatically start playing the video stream.  Might not be exactly what you were looking for since the thumbnail is covered by a play arrow, but it is an option.